# How to Stop Chart.js Rendering Over Previous Chart

Tags: javascript, chart.js

I've put together some code which allows me to query a MySQL database, return the result and populate a chart.js. The problem being that each time the AJAX code runs the chart is rendered over the previous one. I've read through a few similar stackoverflow queries which are recommending the use of `myChart.destroy();` or other solutions but I' struggling to work out where this should be inserted into the following code.

Note that I've simplified the code below for simplicity sake.

Any assistance on how to stop this chart 'ghosting' occuring would be greatly appreciated.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(document).ready( function($) {
    var valueCheck;
    jQuery('#afl_player_year').on( 'change', function () {
         afl_player_year = $('#afl_player_year').val();
     jQuery.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php",
        dataType: "json", 
        data: {
            action: 'call_player_chart_data',
            afl_player_year: afl_player_year,
        },
         success:function(output){
             var y_data1 = output[0];
             var y_data2 = output[1];
             var x_time  = ............
new Chart(document.getElementById("myChart"), {
   type: 'bar',
    data: {
      labels: x_time,
      datasets: [{.........
      }, {.........
      }]
    },
    options: {
      scales: {.........
       yAxes: [{.........},{.........},
        }]
      }
    }
});
         }
     });
    }).change();
});
</script>
```

Comment: Please provide a minimal, complete, and verifiable example. https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Also, check out the documentation on updating a chart: https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/developers/updates.html